# F# function parameters

Tags: f#

I have 2 lines of code here:

```
let stuff _ _ = MessageBox.Show("This is doing stuff") |> ignore
let stuffHandler = new EventHandler(stuff)
```

I just started with F# and would like to know why the code does not compile if I remove underscores
from stuff variable? As far as I know underscore means to ignore something so what should be ignored here?

Comment: Hint: Given `new EventHandler(stuff)`, you can infer that ;p

Comment: So you mean it has something to do with parameters? It must have void return type so how _ _ does it make return void? )

Comment: @Micha it doesn't. The EventHandler constructor expects a function that takes two arguments. The `_`s make `stuff` a two argument function -- each `_` is a formal parameter name. It's just a convention to name things you don't need with an `_`.

Answer (score 6):

The [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) delegate expects a function with 2 parameters, the sender and the EventArgs.